# Word VBA: How to delete sections of text from a template document using a heading

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template document that contains sections that are not all required at any one time for the produced document. I am using a user form with VBA to create a list of headings (sections) that will need to be deleted from the document.

```
Private Sub Delete_Click()
    Set rngHeader = ActiveDocument.Range.Find("Test")
    rngHeader.Select
    Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

I understand that I'll need to loop through the document while looping through the headings list, but unsure on the logic for this.

I am completely new to VBA and VB in general so not sure on how I should/can go about this.

Thanks for any advice!
It's really appreciated

Comment: Firstly please ensure that you use the terminology correctly as this helps in understanding your question correctly. The terms "section", "heading", and "header" all have specific meanings in Word. Blocks of text preceded by a "heading" are not "sections", which are defined by section breaks and are used to achieve changes in page layout.

Comment: Secondly, are the headings formatted with a heading style? If not what you are attempting will be much more complicated.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Hi yeah sorry about the incorrect terms. I have the headings formatted with Heading1 heading style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have formatted the headings with heading styles the following function should get you somewhere close.

Heading styles have an assigned outline level which runs from 1 to 9 with 1 being the highest. Word has a built-in bookmark "\HeadingLevel" which can be used to return all the text below the heading. The range will end at the next heading of the same level or higher. So if you are looking for a heading with outline level of 2 the range will end at a heading 1 or heading 2. Any text at levels 3-9 or "Body Text" (the very lowest level) will be included in the range.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim rngHeading As Range
  Set rngHeading = GetHeadingBlock("Heading text you want to find", wdStyleHeading1)
  If Not rngHeading Is Nothing Then rngHeading.Delete
End Sub

Function GetHeadingBlock(headingText As String, headingStyle As WdBuiltinStyle) As Range
  Dim rngFind As Range
  Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.Content
  With rngFind.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = headingText
    .style = headingStyle
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    If .Execute Then Set GetHeadingBlock = _
      rngFind.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, name:="\HeadingLevel")
  End With
End Function
```