# Get table values from certain section in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large word document that has several tables in several different sections. Something that looks like the following:

- Section 1

  - Section 1.1 (has table)
  - Section 1.2

    - Section 1.2.1 (has table)
- Section 2

  - Section 2.1 (has table)

    - Section 2.1.1 (has table)
  - Section 2.2
- Section 3 (has table)

However, I only want the tables in one section. Is there a way to create a loop that can get the data from all the tables only in a certain section?

I was thinking about using something like `ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1)`, but I think I'll need more than that. Is there a way to constantly check which section you're in? Maybe some pseudocode like...

```
'Starting at the top of the document
'This would not start until the document found Section 2, and would end once it found section 3

While [ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents("name")]    
'Which would include 2.1, 2.1.1, and 2.2 because they are a part of 2 
    TableCount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count   'But only header 2
    For tableNum = 1 To TableCount
        ' do something/get data
    Next tableNum
Wend
```

Comment: Be careful about how you use terminology. The term “section” has a special meaning in Word. It is a document part that contains page layout, headers, footers etc.., which can be terminated by a section break. What you have described in your question is a “heading level”.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thanks for the heads up. I searched around for how to get heading levels and found TablesOfContents object. Do you think this would work for this application?

Comment: Your question shows naivety in two places.  1. You don't say if the section titles are word headings or not.  2. You don't clarify if your term 'sections' actually refers to Word sections (text between section breaks) or is just a term you are using for a heading.  If you wish to get sensible answers to your question please edit your post to clarify these two points.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is find the Heading 1 styled paragraph that marks the start of the range you want to look in. You can then use the document’s [`GoTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.goto) method to go to the [predefined bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks) that will give you the entire range of the heading level, starting at the Heading 1 para and extending to the next Heading 1 para.
You can then access the `Tables` collection of that [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range)

Don’t have access to a PC right now to give you the code, but there are numerous examples here on SO, for example [Word VBA: How to delete sections of text from a template document using a heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149722/word-vba-how-to-delete-sections-of-text-from-a-template-document-using-a-headin/63156126#63156126) (purely conicidental that it is one of mine!)